# Unable to notify bugsense error report

Tags: javascript, bugsense

I'm executing below code to report bugsense regarding error. However, I'm unable to do so.

```
  var bugsense = new Bugsense({
    // TODO change API key
      apiKey : <API_KEY>
    });
  bugsense.addExtraData('LEVEL', 'fake');
  bugsense.addExtraData('TYPE', 'fake');
  bugsense.leaveBreadcrumb('Bread Crum Test');

  try {
    fakeFunction();
  } catch (error) {
    bugsense.notify(error, "Some URL", "My line Number", {
      fake : 'Some custom data object'
    });
    alert("Bug Logged");
  }
```

Below is the error log I'm getting on console.
/bugsense.min.js: Line 3 : logged 1 error to Bugsense, status: {"data": null, "error": "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"}